# Lua function for string.match multiple words and numbers

Tags: search, lua, lua-patterns

If I have a search box and want to find if a string contains certain words (not case sensitive) and/or numbers.

```
search = "Brown lazy 46"
textline = "The quick brown fox jumped over 46 lazy dogs"
if string.match(textline, search) then
  result = textline
end
```

just like a web search.

Comment: What have you tied to do to solve this problem? first obvious solution is loop over your search terms and check they are in the text provided.

Comment: [This](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
search = "Brown lazy 46"
textline = "The quick brown fox jumped over 46 lazy dogs"

for item in string.gmatch(search, "%S+") do 
if string.find(textline, string.lower(item)) then
   result = textline
    end
end
```

You break up the word values ​​you are looking for and convert them into an array. Then you should loop that array and check if your main variable is in it.

If I understood correctly what you want to do this should solve your problem.

Comment: I just had to change it all to lowercase it to work    "if string.find(string.lower(textline), string.lower(item)) then"